# iPhone App Converted to Universal, works fine on device, but validation fails with message "Nib file not found"

Tags: ios

I already searched stackoverflow.com, followed the instructions from Answered posts, but nothing works for me. So, this is not a duplicate post.

I developed my app for iPhone, uploaded and it's already in the app store. Now I made it as universal App and made some slight changes for iPad view.

```
bool IsIPad=[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

if (IsIpad)
{
    //do something specific for iPad view
}
```

It's all working fine in the simulator/device. But fails when I attempt to upload to appstore. I tried creating Main-iPad.storyboard, the app shows black screen.
When I remove "Main nib file base name (iPad)", the validation succeeds, but I can't upload it because it only shows blank screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

- I created another Universal App Project. It created 2 storyboards, each for iPhone and iPad.
- Copied the iPad storyboard file to my original project to Base.lproj folder.
- Dragged and dropped the storyboard file (Main-iPad.storyboard) to my project.
- Created Archive and ran the validation. Everything worked fine, uploaded it to App Store, and waiting for approval.

The reason I didn't create a new storyboard on my original project was that it creates a blank storyboard with 'no scenes' message. I didn't want to deal with the hassle of figuring out how to fix that issue. So I gave a shot with my above solution, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're focusing on the wrong validation message. Look at the other one: it says your Info.plist refers to *both* the Storyboard and the XIB file. It should only have one -- I assume the XIB file. So you should edit the Info.plist and remove the bits where it talks about Storyboards.

Comment: I can't find the .xib file. I guess it's called .storyboard now? there is only one storyboard file. So I duplicated it and named it Main-iPad.storyboard.

Comment: Don't duplicate your storyboard. Look in the info.plist and fix that. Storyboard get "compiled" down to NIB files.